# Load different angular controller at click of a button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I am working on a Single Page Application. Page A , Page B are partials.
We have a button "btnA" on "Page A" rendered using "controllerA". At click of "btnA" we need to perform "serviceA.somework()" and at successful completion, load "Page B" using "controllerB" with some params.

Is following the best way to achieve this?

within controllerA.onClickBtnA() { $location.path(PageB).search({param:'value'})}

Comment: This is a rather open question but I can't see why this is bad? In this scenario the viewmodel/controller is the glue between all logic.

Answer (score 1):

[`$routeProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) is the best choice for your scenario. You should not load the controller *manually* in any way. The Angular `router` does the job for you.

A simple example from the [angular official API page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider): http://plnkr.co/edit/foLnNL7koXzUYavnYFFw?p=preview.

---

#### Update

Your proposal is basically doing what `$routeProvider` does. `$routeProvider` provides:

1. RegExp in path definition
2. Browsing history
3. A `resolve` function to control access to current path
4. Place to define your controller and template for each path
5. Mechanism to deal with path parameters
6. ...

And it is well tested and supported. You'd better have a try.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please point out what will be the major pros in this option with the cons in the one posted in the original question?